# Back up of sub site only in SharePoint 2010

Tags: backup, restore, sub-site

I am having a subsite (test) with 69 subsites under it. But I want only to take back up of the first sub site(test) and restore it back. Can some one suggest on how to do it. when I am using export import powershell commands its pulling all the 69 subsites residing under this subsite(test).

Comment: Is saving the site as a template a viable alternative? Just append `_layouts/savetmpl.aspx` to the end of the site URL.

Comment: cellv2 saving template is not working as the site is over 500mb